# Removing format,args from System.out.printf(format, args). Currently using NetBeans IDE17

Tags: netbeans, autofill

I'm using NetBeans IDE17, when I want to type

```
System.out.printf()
```

as soon as I hit the open bracket '(', it auto replace with

```
System.out.printf(format, args)
```

where can I remove the auto suggestion/fill?

Tried finding in Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion and failed.

Comment: Did you try **Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion**, then selecting _Java_ from the **Language** drop list, and then unchecking the **Guess Filled Method Arguments** checkbox?

Comment: Tried that, the auto fill still came in.

Comment: I'm baffled then. That is exactly what I did on NetBeans 17, and it worked fine for me. That is, if  the **Guess Filled Method Arguments** checkbox is unchecked and I type `System.out.printf(` then all NetBeans does is add a closing right bracket. Double check that your **Guess Filled Method Arguments** checkbox really is unchecked on the **Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion** screen when _Java_ is selected. If so, then update your question with a screen shot.

Comment: Maybe also try restarting NetBeans after the configuration change to see if that helps, though I don't think that should really be necessary.

Comment: Found the issue. It is in Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion > Java > **Completion Selectors for Java**.  Removed the open bracket over there and it stopped auto filling format and args. Even though I unchecked the guess filled method, same issue arise.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion > Java > **Completion Selectors for Java** and remove the open bracket to stop auto filling.
[Netbeans Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnAdg.png)